# XML array deserialization as a List property fails

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize a class that has a field of type ConcurrentBag.

This was my approach:

```
public class XmlSerializable
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ConcurrentBag<string> Array = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Array")]
    public List<string> ArrayXml { get { return Array.ToList(); } set { Array = new ConcurrentBag<string>(value); } }
}
```

When I try to serialize it, everything looks good, but when I try to deserialize it back, the array is empty.

```
    XmlSerializable serializable = new XmlSerializable();
    serializable.Array.Add("entry1");

    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlSerializable));
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true });
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, serializable);
    string xml = stringWriter.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(xml);

    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlSerializable));

    XmlSerializable deserialized = (XmlSerializable)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    Console.WriteLine(deserialized.Array.Count);
```

Here is the snippet output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<XmlSerializable xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Array>entry1</Array>
</XmlSerializable>
0
```

As you can see, the serialization works, but at deserialization, the array is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be working when class is defined like this:

```
public class XmlSerializable
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ConcurrentBag<string> Array = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Array")]
    public string[] ArrayXml { get { return Array.ToArray(); } set { Array = new ConcurrentBag<string>(value); } }
}
```

The property has to be `string[]` instead of `List<string>`. Weird though, since it works with fields of type `List<T>`, but apparently not with properties of type `List<T>`.